# Swing lost exception

Tags: java, swing, exception

When i start modal dialog and when it render exception occur, that exception goes somewhere. Can I catch it in code that invoke dialog.setVisible()?

P.S. I know about Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler, I need catch it from code that invoke that dialog.

P.P.S. In advance thanks, Andrey/.

```
public class TestSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
                    JTable table = new JTable();
                    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {
                        @Override public int getColumnCount() {return 1;}
                        @Override public int getRowCount() {return 1;}
                        @Override
                        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Hello");
                        }
                    });

                    jDialog.add(table);
                    jDialog.setModal(true);
                    jDialog.pack();
                    jDialog.setVisible(true);

                    System.out.println("dialog closed");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("got it");
               }

           }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cann't because the exception is not in your dialog, but in the thread. Dialog.setVisible() waits until the dialog goes invisible, but don't stop the current thread. But I have a trick for you, which probably helps you to get the desired behavior.

```
public class TestSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
                    JTable table = new JTable();
                    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {
                        @Override public int getColumnCount() {return 1;}
                        @Override public int getRowCount() {return 1;}
                        @Override
                        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Hello");
                        }
                    });

                    jDialog.add(table);
                    jDialog.setModal(true);
                    jDialog.pack();
                    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                            jDialog.setVisible(false);
                            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(null);
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    });
                    jDialog.setVisible(true);

                    System.out.println("dialog closed");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("got it");
               }

           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have mentioned before, I know that approach

Comment: @user2539361 Try to run my code. The exception is caught in the catch block. So you get the output "got it". There is no another solution for your problem.